# What is the use of access token and access secret tokens while logging in via facebook, google and twitter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, access-token, facebook-access-token

Is it necessary to store access tokens and access secret tokens in database? What if I don't? What is the significance of access tokens while allowing users to log in to my website?

Secondly, if the user updates their email id in facebook, how will it be updated in my database for that particular account?I can get the email id and other details using facebook sdk api and store those details in my database, now what if the user updates their email id? How should I deal with this scenario?

Comment: Access tokens are used to tell the API(s) what user your are making a request on behalf of. And if the user updates their email on FB – well then you simply request that field they next time they login via Facebook, and update it in your database if it has changed …

Comment: Is it necessary to store access tokens in database? Are they used to recognize the users? Should I recognize the user by its access token or by its email address?

Comment: You need their access token before you will even get their email address (if you will get email at all, which is not a given.) Whether you store access tokens, or use the “fresh” one you get each time when they login, depends on what specifically you want to do with them. // This question is very broad, too broad actually. You should probably go do some more research first, look at how others have implemented this, etc.